# Need help/tips for putting formulas in prenex normal form

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the formula's $\forall x \space P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$ and $\forall x \space P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)$.

Solving one:

1. $\forall x \space P(x) \rightarrow Q(y)$
2. $\neg \forall x \space  P(x) \vee Q(y)$      implication-elimination
3. $\exists x \space \neg P(x) \vee Q(y)$       duality (don't know English word for it)
4. $\exists x \space \neg P(x) \vee \exists x \space Q(y)$ free Existential quantification
5. $\exists x \space (\neg P(x) \vee \space Q(y))$ distribution of $\exists x$ over $\vee$
6. $\exists x \space (P(x) \rightarrow Q(y))$ implication-elimination

Could someone tell me if this is correct?

And as well, I keep thinking this should also work for the other formula, $\forall x \space P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$, but then I have to make sure the second $x$ is not free. Can I just rename it?

Comment: Is $\forall x p\to q$ or $\forall x (p\to q)$ in the first formula?

Comment: It is the first one, so no brackets around $\forall x \space P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in both cases, the variables $x$, $y$, respectively, are "free" (not bound, as the scope of the universal quantifier is limited to the predicate $P(x)$).

So each statement says precisely the same thing.

But yes, in your proof of the first statement, you'd need to rename the variable prior to step $4$, i.e., replace $x$ in $Q(x)$ by, say, $y$, or $z$ (i.e., by any variable other than $x$) so it remains *free* in subsequent steps of the proof.

I'd suggest that you approach the entire problem by first stating $$\forall xP(x) \rightarrow Q(x) \equiv \forall xP(x) \rightarrow Q(y)$$

And then follow with your proof, as is, since it will then cover both statements, since they are logically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, I have a hard time with prenex normal forms and knowing all the ins and outs of when and how with free variables. It does seem like I'm on the right track here.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Your work looks "top-notch", and your intuition was "spot-on."

Comment: Wow, thanks for the kind words!